# ActiveRecord count

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

Here I retrieve a collection of `causes` from the database. Along with the information from each `cause`, I want to send the number of `users` in each `cause`.  This way works, but if experience has told me anything there is probably a much more efficient method to do this.  How can I improve this?

```
  def index
    @causes = Cause.near([params[:lat], params[:lng]],10)
    @causes.each do |i|
      i['count'] = i.users.count
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {:success=> 1, :data_type => 'cause',:results => @causes} }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform an inner-join on the users table and then group by the causes.id.

```
@causes = Cause
  .near([params[:lat], params[:lng]], 10)
  .joins('users')
  .group('causes.id')
  .select('causes.*, count(users) as count')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not trying to be a smart ass, but is this better or just different? Can you explain why? Thanks

Comment: This is more efficient because the number of queries to database is reduced to one. It also places the work onto the database which is optimized for this task through caching and indexing.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It doesn't seem to work. More info posted above :)

Comment: @user15872  What does `Cause.select('causes.id,count(users) as people').joins(:users).group('causes.id').first.people` output?

Comment: Making progress. It gives the right answer as far as count is concerned: "2". It's not part of a hash though :(

Comment: I think it is there, try to render the JSON and it should be there.

Comment: Nope, still returns "2". The mystery continues... I posted some more of my model info, maybe there is something there that I'm not catching. Thanks again!

Comment: You say its not in the hash but AR is not returning a hash it is returning a ActiveRecord::Relation. What it is printing to the screen is not necessarily what will be in the json. What does this show? Cause.select('causes.id,count(users) as people').joins(:users).group('causes.id').as_json

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I'm also pretty new to AR also.  Last question, can you expand on your last comment a little more? I've been aware of the as_json function, but I've been just using the `render json:` method to   send my responses. Is this bad practice? (This might be a stupid question as I might be missing something obvious.)

Comment: I think your way of using `render json:` is the best because it is idiomatic rails.

Comment: This might be greedy but I have a small follow up.`Cause.near([params[:lat], params[:lng]],10).select('causes.*,count(users) as peeps').joins(:users).group('causes.id').as_json` works like a charm. I have a similar function, I can't get to work because I can't alias it in my SQL Statement.`Cause.distance_to([params[:lat], params[:lng]]).select('causes.*,count(users) as peeps').joins(:users).group('causes.id').where("users.id = #{current_user.id}").as_json` As far as I am aware, `distance_to` will work on a single AR resource but won't give me the distance of item in the collection. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with geocoder but you can find out what the query is doing by running `Cause.distance_to([params[:lat], params[:lng]]).select('causes.*,count(users) as peeps').joins(:users).group('causes.id').where("users.id = #{current_user.id}").to_sql`. Maybe that will provide you with the column names.